# Jedis connection in Spring fails to authenticate on Redis

Tags: redis, spring-data, jedis

I have a spring boot application connecting to Redis via tls and password.

I'm using the following configuration to instantiate the RedistTemplate and JedisConnection

```
 @Bean
  JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
     RedisStandaloneConfiguration conf = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host,port);
     conf.setPassword(RedisPassword.of("myPassword"));
     JedisConnectionFactory jedisConFactory = null;
     JedisClientConfiguration confJedis = JedisClientConfiguration.builder().useSsl().build();
     jedisConFactory =  new JedisConnectionFactory(conf,confJedis);
     //jedisConFactory.setPassword("myPassword");
     return jedisConFactory;
  }


 @Bean
  public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
      RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
      template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
      return template;
  }
```

I receive the following error:

```
class org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageExceptionNOAUTH Authentication required.; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: NOAUTH Authentication required.
```

Which seems to be an error from Redis not receiving a password.

Before enabling TLS configuration on redis I was using this configuration:

```
  @Bean
  JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
     RedisStandaloneConfiguration conf = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host,port);
     conf.setPassword(RedisPassword.of("myPassword"));
     JedisConnectionFactory jedisConFactory = null;
     jedisConFactory =  new JedisConnectionFactory(conf);
     return jedisConFactory;
  }
```

And it was working just fine.
So something in "how" I set the password in the Jedis configuration with TLS is not working, I even used the deprecated method (commented in the snippet above):

```
//jedisConFactory.setPassword("myPassword");
```

to see if it may work but without success.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding .and().usePooling() to the code as follows:

```
JedisClientConfiguration confJedis = JedisClientConfiguration.builder().useSsl().and().usePooling().build();
```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62333351)